# ViewPager with tabLayout - Child Fragment takes time to change

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, android-viewpager

** View Pager with tabLayout at bottom in View Pager adapter using to switch a fragment to each tab.the issue is that are functionality are working fine. but the fragment in tab switch are show jerk in the  change to another fragment.**

Fragment are using to call api with the separated thread.

```
private void createViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    TabLayoutViewPagerAdapter adapter = new TabLayoutViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFrag(homePageFragment);
    adapter.addFrag(orderHistoryFragment);
    adapter.addFrag(supportFragment);
    adapter.addFrag(new AccountDetailsFragment());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(viewPager.getAdapter().getCount());
}
```

ViewPager Adapter

```
public class TabLayoutViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<String> getmFragmentTitleList() {
        return mFragmentTitleList;
    }

    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public TabLayoutViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    public void addFrag(Fragment fragment) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
    }
}
```

activity xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/tabs"
            android:background="@color/white"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@drawable/tablayout_bg"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/zotocolor"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/zotocolor"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/black" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change viewpager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2) or by default it is set to 1 and check the loading time as you don't need to keep every fragment in memory which leads to slow response of loading in view pager.

Check this for more info about setOffscreenPagLimit in viewpager https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit%28int%29